# How does the Linux kernel initialize the mem_map array on 64 bit systems?

Tags: linux, kernel

I know that the Linux kernel keeps track of the status of each physical page frame with the help of a C structure `struct page`. The structures for all page frames form an array `mem_map[]`of type `struct page` so that you can easily retrieve the structure for a specific page frame by using the page frame number as the index.
On a x86 32 bit system with 4 GiB of physical memory the array is made up of 2<sup>20</sup> entries, because of a page size of 4096 bytes, each of size of 32 bytes, so the complete array consumes 32 MiB.
Now, when I transfer this to a x86 64 bit system with for example 4 TiB of physical memory, then the array is made up of 2<sup>30</sup> entries, each of size of 32 bytes, so the array consumes 32 GiB. Of course, with more physical memory the array could increase to a maximum of 32 TiB if the platform specific limit of 4 PiB (2<sup>52</sup> bytes on amd64 architecture) is reached.
Does the kernel really have to initialize that big amount of data at startup or is there something I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different [physical memory models](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/vm/memory-model.html) used by the Linux kernel: the flat model which you describe, the discontiguous memory model, and the sparse memory model.

Most (if not all) 64-bit architectures supported by Linux use the latter by default. It relies on memory sections, and a virtually allocated memory map on most architectures. The entries required to represent the physical memory actually present are allocated and initialised as necessary. On large systems, this initialisation can even be deferred so that it doesn’t delay the boot.

Answer (score 0):

https://lwn.net/Articles/839737/ (12/11/2020) still says "page structures typically take up just over 1.5% of the available memory". I think the percentage comes from 64/4096 = 1.5625%.

In my M416s_v2 Ubuntu 20.04 VM that has 5700 GB memory and runs on Azure, the overhead is 1.5657%, which is close to 1.5625%:

"cat /proc/meminfo |grep MemTotal:" shows: "MemTotal:       5882783592 kB"

(I reserve 512MB memory for Linux kdump): "cat /proc/cmdline" shows "BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1010-azure root=PARTUUID=7327629e-2b41-4f48-893e-9ae930552551 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 earlyprintk=ttyS0 crashkernel=512M panic=-1"

1 - (5882783592 / (5700.0 * 1024 *1024 - 512 * 1024)) = 0.015657580372575808

(5700 * 1024 * 1024) * (0.015657580372575808 - 64.0/4096) / 1024 = 190.16511865047505

Except the page structures, the kernel/driver code/data/BSS uses about 190 MB. Here let's ignore the memory reserved by the firmware.